# Probability that a chosen card is greater than another chosen card, mistake in my "proof"

Tags: probability, solution-verification, card-games

I want to solve this problem.

> Consider a deck of 52 cards, ordered such that Ace > King > Queen > ... > 2. I pick a card, then you pick one. What is the probability that my card is larger than yours?

I thought of doing it like this, but it is wrong and I don't see why.

Denote the cards by values 1 to 13, so the card "2" is denoted by 1 and the card "Ace" is denoted by 13. This is just a transformation.

Let $p$ be the desired probability. Then
$$p = \sum_{i=1} P(\text{my card} > \text{your card } | \text{ I pick card of value i})P(\text{I pick card of value i})$$
by law of total probability.

We have
$$P(\text{I pick card of value i}) = \frac{4}{52} = \frac{1}{13}$$
since there are   4 cards of value $i$ in a deck (eg. there are 4 aces in a deck).

We also have
$$P(\text{my card} > \text{your card} | \text{I pick card of value i}) = \frac{i-1}{12} + \frac{i-1}{13}\times 3$$
because if I pick a card of value $i$ then the cards $1, ..., i-1$ are smaller than my card, and there are 12 cards from the suite my card is from and 13 cards in the 3 remaining suites.

So we get

$$p= \frac{1}{13}\times (\frac{1}{12} + \frac{3}{13})\times \sum_{i=1}^{13} i-1 = \frac{1}{13}\times (\frac{1}{12} + \frac{3}{13})\times 66$$
and this is bigger than $1$. What's the error in my method and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hard to follow. Note that either you get a tie or the two players have equal chances of winning.

Comment: What did you do to get $\frac{i-1}{12}+\frac{i-1}{13}\times 3$?  What makes you think those numbers specifically?  Recall, there are $51$ cards left in the deck after the first player gets their card... so where does $12$ come from?  Why not $51$?

Comment: It sounds like you mean to have $\dfrac{(i-1) + (i-1)\times 3}{12+13\times 3}$ which is simply $\dfrac{(i-1)\times 4}{51}$ instead... Note that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}\neq \frac{a+c}{b+d}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Let's split the 52 cards in the deck into 4 groups of 13 cards (hearts, spades, etc). If I pick let's say the ace from the first group, then that group has 12 cards remaining. The other three groups have 13 cards left in the deck, so that's how I did it. Does it make sense?

Comment: @JMoravitz Hmm, I thought I was splitting it somehow using the rule $P(A \text{ or }B) = P(A) + P(B)$

Comment: No, because neither of you draws from different groups of the deck. Your opponent draws 1 card from the 51 left, and $4\times (i-1)$ are good for you.

Comment: @Ingix OK I think I understand

Comment: In addition, your forumula becomes almost $4$ for $i=13$.

Comment: "*I thought I was splitting it using $P(A\text{ or }B)=P(A)+P(B)$.*" your interpretation of your $A$'s and $B$'s are off.  $A$ the event "second card is smaller and comes from same suit", $B$ the event "second card is smaller and comes from different suit."  Your value of $\frac{i-1}{12}$ is the **conditional** probability of the second card being smaller *given that* it comes from the same suit. As for $\frac{i-1}{13}\times 3$, you mean to have $\frac{(i-1)\times 3}{13\times 3}$ or more simply $\frac{i-1}{13}$ is the **conditional** probability of the second smaller given from different suit

Comment: P(my card>your card|I pick card of value i) is already greater than $1$.

Comment: The probability "second card smaller *given that* it comes from the same suit" is not the same thing as the probability "second card is smaller *and* it comes from the same suit."  $\Pr(X\mid Y)\neq \Pr(X\cap Y)$.  If you wanted to correct this line of thinking, you would need to *condition* those probabilities on their conditionals... multiply by the probability of that conditional being the case.  $\frac{i-1}{12}\times\frac{12}{51} + \frac{i-1}{13}\times\frac{39}{51}$, which of course equals as alluded to before $\frac{(i-1)\times 4}{51}$

Comment: @JMP How did you arrive at this conclusion ?

Comment: @Peter; if $i>4$. OP only says that the probability is >1 on last line, but it already is by this line.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct (and simpler) expression is
$$P(\text{my card} > \text{your card} | \text{I pick card of value i}) = \frac{(i-1)\times 4}{51}$$

Simply: the numerator is the possible cards that are lower than $i$, and $51$ are the available cards.

AS noted in the comments, this can be expressed as

$$ \dfrac{(i-1) + (i-1)\times 3}{12+13\times 3}$$

where the first terms in each sum correspond to the selected rank. But this does not really help. And of course, the mistake amounts to assuming $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}\neq \frac{a+c}{b+d}$
This is already noted by
JMoravitz' comment.